# ODataQueryOptions<T> throws self referencing loop error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am trying to call a Web API using postman with ODataQueryOptions. But I am getting error

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'DeclaringType' with type 
>   -'Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmEntityType'. Path 'messageArguments[0].options.Context.Model.SchemaElements[0].DeclaredProperties[0]'.

Below is the API ActionMethod -

```
    [Route("api/get")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Dummy> options)
    {
         return null;
    }
```

My Postman URL - https://localhost:44360/api/get/$select=Name

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Qpe.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had an action filter on that action method which will convert the action parameters into JSON using Newtonsoft and log them in a text file. The issue was with converting the ODataQueryOptions into JSON, which resulted in self-referencing loop error. Adding ignore self-reference JSON setting while converting to JSON gave rise to another error - "error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'". Anyway, I removed the action filter and it works fine now.